# Which collection is better to use in MapReduce Program(Java)

Tags: java, collections, mapreduce

Recently I have created a MapReduce program in Java and in mappers and reducers code I use TreeMap. And after submitting the code I got the response that, 'the use of local data structure is not preferable'.

So My question is, how it will affect the program if I use TreeMap or any other Map, and if not TreeMap, can I use ArrayList?

Comment: Where do you use the TreeMap? Only in Mapper/Reducer Code?

Comment: Yes only in mapper and reducer as a global variable

Comment: OK then there is no reason to avoid TreeMap. Maybe they mean, to use commons library for TreeMap Classes (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/FastTreeMap.html)

Comment: From where you got the response - the use of local data structure is not preferable? As far I know, `mapreduce` program running on `apache hadoop` ifrastructure do not throw any such warning.

Comment: I got the answer. We are dealing with big data so it may create the problem of memory overhead if we use treemap in our code.